# Blurry text when transition css

Tags: html, css

I have code below for a flip card animiation I am trying to create using pure css. Why when I have my flip animation css code does the text and image get blurry, yet when I take out the flip code the text goes back to being nice and sharp? Is there anyway to fix this issue? Does anyone have any solutions? Anything helps, thanks. (I am viewing this in Google Chrome).

**With flip css**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');

html, body { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  background-color:#eaeaea;}

.container {
  width:900px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.right-div {
  width:540px;
  height:550px;
  background-image:url();
  transform:scale(1);
  background-position: -170px 0px; 
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.left-div {
  width:323px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.content-name {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7E7E7E;    
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top:160px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-title {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-description {
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-link {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left:40px;}





/*Flip*/

.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 900px;
 height: 550px;}

.flipper {
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 position: relative;}

.front, .back {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;}

.front {
  z-index: 2;}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: white;}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">
      <p class="content-name">title</p>
      <p class="content-title">name</p>
    <p class="content-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus <br/> error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      :p
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Without flip css**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i');

html, body { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  background-color:#eaeaea;}

.container {
  width:900px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.right-div {
  width:540px;
  height:550px;
  background-image:url();
  transform:scale(1);
  background-position: -170px 0px; 
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.left-div {
  width:323px;
  height:550px;
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;}

.content-name {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #7E7E7E;    
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top:160px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-title {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-description {
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-left:40px;}

.content-link {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left:40px;}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">
      <p class="content-name">title</p>
      <p class="content-title">name</p>
    <p class="content-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus <br/> error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    <a href="#" class="content-link">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      :p
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On my screen it only blurs while actively flipping. Have you tried looking at it from a different computer?

Comment: Not yet, no. Are you using chrome as well? Why does it blur when flipping?

Comment: I think it works as intended, you can't get the flip without a bit of blur. To be honest, I don't notice it.

Comment: Yes, Chrome, on mac. It blurs because its moving.

Comment: Hmm, odd. Mines blurry without activating the animation. Maybe it's the laptop I am currently using.

Comment: @amflare When you run both snippets, both text samples look the same?

Comment: Aside from flipping, yeah.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/ Anyone who suffers from blurry text should read this old article by Paul Lewis. In short it's mainly all about Subpixel antialiasing quirks.